# Magick++ Issue when converting to Mat Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick-convert, magick++

Good day everyone,

I have this problem which I need to convert the Magick++ Image to OpenCV Mat. Though I successfully converted it however the problem occurs which the color of the Mat is not correct (Please see attached Image). In my case, I have a PDF file which I converted it to Magick++ Image page by page and to use my Image Processing methods, I need to convert it to OpenCV Mat. When I use other PDF file, the colors are correct. I really appreciate any help in this issue, Thanks.
My working code is displayed below, thanks.
Note: I use ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16 and OpenCV 2.4.11

```
try {
    string fName = "";
    vector<Magick::Image> imageList;
    cout << "Please Input the File name of the PDF." << endl;
    cin >> fName;
    cout << "Please wait while converting the PDF to Images...." << endl;
    readImages(&imageList, fName);
    bool isDecoded = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++){
        if (!isDecoded){

            int w = imageList[i].columns();
            int h = imageList[i].rows();

            Mat opencvImage(h,w,CV_8UC4);

            imageList[i].write(0, 0, w, h, "RGBA" , Magick::CharPixel, opencvImage.data);

            string decoded = QRScanner(opencvImage);
            imshow("opencvImage", opencvImage);
            if (decoded != ""){
                cout << "Result: " << decoded << endl;
                isDecoded = true;
            }

            waitKey();
        }
    }
}
catch (Magick::Exception &error_)
{
    cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
}
cout << "Convert Complete!" << endl;
system("pause");
```

[Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkXV.png)
[Image Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEAwJ.jpg)

Comment: You did not seem to attach the image. Also, please post a minimal working example of your code.

Comment: Please actually post the code. On Stack Overflow, you can get it to display by code by indenting the whole block of code by at least four spaces and inserting into your post. It's easier for people to read the code and the problem statement together, and also makes it possible for others to copy/paste your code if they want to try to run it. Help others help you :). Either way is it possible that the order of channels is what is wrong here? Most libraries read images as RGB, but OpenCV uses BGR order instead. You can use `cvtColor()` from OpenCV.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks :) I am new to this.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I tried the cvtColor of Opencv but the colors are still not in the right place. The background which contains the QRCode still in black. Thanks btw

Comment: How did you use `cvtColor()`? I'm pretty sure you're writing the channels in R, G, B order and not B, G, R order, so `cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)` before displaying should work.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I tried that `cvtColor(opencvImage, opencvImage, COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);` but no luck.

Comment: It looks inverted to me - try inverting it as a quick test.

Comment: @MarkSetchell WOW!!! THAT WORKS!!! Thanks Mark :D I am really thankful :)

Comment: If the colors look inverted, it is likely that your PDF is in CMYK colorspace. For best conversion, use profiles to convert to sRGB. Negating the channels kind of works, but does not give the best results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the majority of the problem has been addressed in the comments above, but I believe this can be quickly fixed by adjusting the channel map to what OpenCV is expecting.

```cpp
imageList[i].write(0, 0, w, h, "BGRA" , Magick::CharPixel, opencvImage.data);
                                ^^^^
```

No need to worry about `cvtColor` or negation as you already can control how the data stream is exported.